# Selenium Get first shadow root element inside parents shadow root

Tags: selenium, polymer, shadow-dom

Currently, I am trying to make my progressive web apps Testing automation using selenium.As All my element I get from different shadow room.
Like

```
 //This function will return the element inside shadow root

 public WebElement GetShadowRoot(WebElement host) {
        WebElement shadowRoot = (WebElement) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].shadowRoot", host);
        return shadowRoot;
    }

WebElement MainHost = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("vrs-
app[page='refine']"));
WebElement shadow1 = GetShadowRoot(MainHost);
WebElement host2 = shadow1.findElement(By.cssSelector("vrs-refine"));
WebElement shadow2 = GetShadowRoot(host2);
System.out.println(shadow2);
WebElement host3 = shadow2.findElement(By.cssSelector("vrs-list-
 generator"));
WebElement shadow3 = GetShadowRoot(host3);
System.out.println(shadow3);
WebElement host4 = shadow3.findElement(By.cssSelector("vrs-single-property-tile:first-child"));
WebElement shadow4 = GetShadowRoot(host4);
```

Using This method I get my HTML element through cssSelector.

Here I am getting the issue of CSS selector `vrs-single-property-tile:first-child"` I have several shadow root at same name only id is different.And ID change dynamically.
Here I want to take this single propery tiles and print the property title and price

Here is my temporary URL so that you can get an idea 
 My goal is to access this element `shadow3.findElements(By.cssSelector("#gtmTitle > h3"));`
Any type of help will be appreciated.

Comment: In such a case when unique locators are changing dynamically like ID in your case...use common locator among all elements and make a list of elements... selenium will take care of rest....iterate through list and print title and price.

Comment: I tried but unfortunately not working